# VB6 install after visual studio 2010/2012/2013

Tags: vb6, ide, installation

Coworker has VS 2015 installed and needs vb6 on his machine.

The popup "service pack setup has detected that the version of the system installed is newer than the update you are applying to it"

Is there a work around for this?

Answer (score -1):

I have both installed on my machine (Windows 7) but I installed VB6 first and then VS 2015.

Comment: Yes, it is easy to do it in that order.